# Django can't display images saved in media folder

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I save uploaded files in a media root called /img/:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'img')
MEDIA_URL = '/img/'
```

And use this template to display every image in that folder:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<ul>
{%  for post in latest_post %}
    <li>{{ post.id }} : {{ post.post_body }} : <img src="{% static "/img/" %}{{ post.post_image }}" alt="{{ post.post_image }}" /> </li>

    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

And I get the right url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/img/birthday.jpg
```

But I get "page not found" error when I open the image. Why is that?

Edit: I just ran manage.py collectstatic but it didn't fix the issue. I still get 404 error.

Comment: Are you using the dev server or are you running in production with `DEBUG=False`

Comment: @DanielHepper: dev server. I just created staticroot but it didn't copy my image files.

Comment: Please post your urls.py

Comment: @Chubak what is your STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT variables assigned to settings.py

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder in your base directory by the name static and store all your css, img, js etc files in it in their respective folders, like this:

```
.
├── css
├── fonts
├── icons
├── img
└── js
```

Run python manage.py collectstatic, this collects all your static files and saves them in a staticroot folder.

After that change your settings.py to the following:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')),
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticroot/static'
```

Comment: I get this error now: Your STATICFILES_DIRS setting is not a tuple or list

Comment: No need to put anything related to static or media files in urls.py, collect static does the work.
And define your root path as:
`import os
ROOT_PATH = os.path.dirname(__file__)`